# ngModel makes prepopulation of input box stop working

Tags: angular, textarea, ngmodel

I have an angular component which provides input box to enter a comment. I initially had as:

```
<textarea class="comment-box" type="text" name="comment" value="{{_input.comment}}"></textarea>
```

This causes comment box to be pre-populated with existing value of comment, if there is any. It works fine.

Now I add ngModel for 2 way binding as:

```
<textarea class="comment-box" type="text" name="comment" [ngModel]="comment" (ngModelChange)="handleCommentChange($event)"
          value="{{_input.comment}}"></textarea>
```

Now when comment is modified, handleCommentChange in component is called. It works, but the pre-population of textarea is no more working and textarea is empty even if comment has an initial value when component loads.

How to have both functionalities at same time?

Comment: What does the `handleCommentChange()` method do?

Comment: shouldn't it be [ngModel]="_input.comment" ? Also I think you don't need value="{{_input.comment}}"

Comment: If this worked, please let me know.. I will move it to answer!

Comment: yes, it worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pls change from

```
[ngModel]="comment"
```

to

```
[ngModel]="_input.comment"
```

Also I think you don't need

```
value="{{_input.comment}}"
```

Answer (score 0):

value = {{_input.comment}} remove this line and [(ngModel)] = "_input.comment" correct this line and your two way binding should work and import ngModel in app.module.ts from @angular\forms module .

Answer (score 0):

In order to achieve two-way data-binding, it should have the *banana in the box* syntax i.e.`[(ngModel)]`. You need to enclose `ngModel` in both curly braces as well as square brackets. It means, combination of event binding and property binding.

So, your code will be like:

```
  <textarea class="comment-box" type="text" name="comment" [(ngModel)]="_input.comment" (ngModelChange)="handleCommentChange($event)"></textarea>
```

Also, if it still doesn't work, then give code for your handleCommentChange() method.